# JQuery AJAX и 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

У меня есть страница, которая в заголовке возвращает 404-ю ошибку. Тем не менее на этой странице есть контент некий (отдизайнеренная страница ошибки). Мне этот контент нужно получить с помощью .load(), но как? В консоль пишет, что такой страницы не существует и отказывается что-либо загружать

Comment: Вопрос интересный. А каким методом запрашиваете страницу? GET? Попробуйте методом PUT, интересно что ответит.

Comment: Никаким методом :) Просто $("#wrapper").load(url + " #wrapper > *");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пробовали сделать так, как написано в документации к [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Если это не срабатывает, то используйте [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), т.к. `load()` - всего лишь "сокращенная" версия `ajax()`.